# Android firebase true way for subscribe to multiple topics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to subscribe to multiple topics?

for loop example in my android app:

```
foreach (String[] all_following_topics_from_user: String topic_name) {
     FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic_name);
}

// example:
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic_name_1");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic_name_2");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic_name_3");
.
.
.
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic_name_589");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic_name_590");
```

Is true way subscribe to all by loop? or exists another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There is currently no other method to subscribe to a topic via the Android client other than the `subscribeToTopic()` method. Another way would be to handle the relationships on your server using the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances):

> **Create a relation mapping for an app instance**
>
> Given a registration token and a supported relationship, you can create a mapping. For example, you can subscribe an app instance to a Google Cloud Messaging topic by calling the Instance ID service at this endpoint, providing the app instance's token as shown:
>
> ```
> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME
> ```

Noting that you would still need to loop from here.

Comment: i use firebase in my app near 1 year, i have not (not save) user instance token on my server (database). i need user token id for this endpoint? if yes, so i should this loop in my app. hoom?

Comment: That's very unfortunate. As far as I've been using FCM, it's always been advised to *save* the token in a trusted environment (app server usually). In order to use the API, you do need the token -- in the link above, you will replace `IID_TOKEN` with the registration token. You mustn't call the API from your app, it has to be done from your server end.

Comment: thanks, i not save tokens in server database. so i have one way. in my app subscribe to all topics useing by loop. yes? no limit for this loop count? no need to delay for any subscribe in loop? for 500 topics in loop is garanted to subscribe all?

Comment: For the loop in the app, I haven't tried using it to sibscribe to that many topics before. So I cant say for sure if there are any limits.